# Calculate the parametric integral $I(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{t}} \cos{tx} \mathrm{d} t$.

Tags: integration, analysis

> Problem: Calculate the closed form of $I(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{t}} \cos{tx} \mathrm{d} t$ and $ J(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{t}} \sin{tx} \mathrm{d} t$.

This is from one analysis homework. Ignore the proof of convergence/existence of $I(x), I^\prime(x), J(x), J^\prime(x)$ and assume they are defined on $\mathbb{R}$. The tips of this problem tells me to take the differential,

\begin{eqnarray*}
I^\prime(x) &=& -\int_0^\infty\sqrt{t}e^{-t}\sin{tx}\mathrm{d}t,\\
J^\prime(x) &=& \int_0^\infty\sqrt{t}e^{-t}\cos{tx}\mathrm{d}t.
\end{eqnarray*}

Integrate by part,
\begin{eqnarray*}
I(x) &=& 2\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\cos{tx}\mathrm{d}\sqrt{t} \\
&=& -2\int_0^\infty \sqrt{t}\mathrm{d}e^{-t}\cos{tx} \\
&=& -2\int_0^\infty -\sqrt{t}e^{-t}\cos{tx} - x\sqrt{t}e^{-t}\sin{tx}\mathrm{d}t\\
&=& 2J^\prime(x) - 2xI^\prime(x),\\
J(x) &=& -2I^\prime(x) - 2xJ^\prime(x).
\end{eqnarray*}

Solve to get 
\begin{eqnarray*}
2I^\prime(x) &=& -J(x) - 2xJ^\prime(x), \\
2J^\prime(x) &=& I(x) + xI^\prime(x).
\end{eqnarray*}

Solve to get 
\begin{eqnarray*}
2(1+x^2)I^\prime(x) + xI(x) &=& -J(x), \\
2(1+x^2)J^\prime(x)+ xJ(x) &=& I(x).
\end{eqnarray*}

How do I continue to get the closed-form of $I(x)$?

Comment: In your very last system, replace $J(x)$ in the second equation by $-2(1+x^2)I'(x)-xI(x)$.

Comment: I get $2J^\prime(x) = I(x) + xI^\prime(x)$. Also differentiate the equation I get $2(1+x^2)I^{\prime\prime} + 6 xI^\prime +\frac{3}{2} I = 0$, which seems unsolvable.

Comment: I don't get "the tips" too. $I(x)+iJ(x)=\sqrt{\pi/(1-ix)}$ (with the principal branch).

Comment: Indeed. You can still write your equation as $X'=A(x)X$ and if you are lucky, $A(s)A(t)=A(t)A(s)$ for all $t,s$ and the solution will be given by $De^{\int_0^x A(t)\,\mathrm d t}$. But I didn't checked that.

Comment: @metamorphy. I was about to write the same. In French, we use an expression which looks like *great minds meet*. The problem is that I am not. Cheers :-)

Comment: @metamorphy Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 2):

If your differential equation is correct $$2(1+x^2)I^{\prime\prime} + 6 xI^\prime +\frac{3}{2} I = 0$$ has as solution
$$I=c_1\frac{ e^{\frac{1}{2} i \tan ^{-1}(x)}}{\sqrt[4]{x^2+1}}+c_2\frac{
   e^{-\frac{1}{2} i \tan ^{-1}(x)}}{\sqrt[4]{x^2+1}}$$

Expanded, this gives (if I am not mistaken)
$$I=\frac{c_1 \left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+1\right)+c_2 x}{ \sqrt{x^2+1}
   \sqrt{1+\sqrt{x^2+1}}}$$